# Append aggregate stats from loop in Pyspark table

Tags: pyspark

I have the following Pyspark code. In each iteration in the loop, I filter out all rows with a particular string in column H. Then I calculate some aggregate stats on column G (results in 3 values). I want to save all the aggregate counts in a single table (rows: CM, NCM, FP; and columns: POP, POP N, POP SN, POP QP).

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Word Count").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()

np.random.seed(0)
rows = 1000
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
   'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
   'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(rows)),dtype='float32'),
   'D' : np.array([3] * rows,dtype='int32'),
   'E' : pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(["test","train","frog", "chicken"], rows)),
   'F' : 'foo' ,
   'G' : np.random.choice(['CM', 'NCM', 'FP'], rows),
   'H' : np.random.choice(['POP', 'POP N', 'POP SN', 'POP QP'], rows)})                                 

df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)
blocks = ['POP', 'POP N', 'POP SN', 'POP QP']

for block in blocks:
    df_spark_trimmed = df_spark.filter(~F.col('H').isin(block))
    counts = df_spark_trimmed.groupby('G').count()
    counts.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
count_by_g = df_spark.groupBy('G').agg(F.count('*').alias('CountByG'))
count_by_gh = df_spark.groupBy(['G', 'H']).agg(F.count('*').alias('CountByGH'))
count_by_g.join(count_by_gh, ['G']).selectExpr(
    'G', 'H', 'CountByG - CountByGH as count'
).groupBy('G').pivot('H').agg(F.max('count').alias('count')).show()

+---+---+-----+------+------+
|  G|POP|POP N|POP QP|POP SN|
+---+---+-----+------+------+
| CM|256|  260|   245|   250|
|NCM|265|  254|   248|   262|
| FP|246|  236|   239|   239|
+---+---+-----+------+------+
```

Or another solution with window functions:

```py
df_spark.groupBy(['G', 'H']).count().selectExpr(
    'G', 'H', 'sum(count) over (partition by G) - count as count'
).groupBy('G').pivot('H').agg(F.max('count').alias('count')).show()
+---+---+-----+------+------+
|  G|POP|POP N|POP QP|POP SN|
+---+---+-----+------+------+
| CM|256|  260|   245|   250|
|NCM|265|  254|   248|   262|
| FP|246|  236|   239|   239|
+---+---+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: But these numbers are incorrect. I'm removing rows that match a string, not selecting rows that match a string

Comment: Fixed it. See the update - You essentially count the total rows first and then subtract the count for each group from it.

Comment: hmm, the result differs from what my script above produces (e.g. the count for POP should be: CM: 256, NCM: 265, FP: 246). I think a pivot table with 4 columns should be subtracted from the single column table: `totalCount = df_spark.groupBy('G').count()`. But not sure how to subtract tables with different numbers of columns...

Comment: `df_spark.groupBy('G').count()` minus `df_spark.groupBy('G').pivot('H').count()` would be the correct solution

Comment: It's more complex than I thought. Updated with a join solution -

Comment: my word. I was hoping it would be simpler. But thanks!

Comment: Updated with a variation using window functions which to some extent is more concise -